# X11 forwarding on docker container

Tags: docker, x11

I'm trying to run GUI apps inside of my docker container and resolve them on the host. I have tried several variations of this command but it always comes back to the same response:

```
Unable to find image 'kali:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for kali, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

However my command seems to be correct. At least from what I can verify online. Can anyone help me out? Here is the command I'm running:

```
docker run --rm -e DISPLAY=10.1.10.460:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -it kali /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because it cannot locate an image.

Official Kali images are located here: https://hub.docker.com/r/kalilinux/kali-last-release